# Tabris UICallback Exception

Tags: eclipse

i want to aktivate the UICallback in tabris on my iPad but when i call `UICallback.aktivate("background")` after each display opperation an IllegalArgumentException is thrown:

```
2012-10-04 11:57:53.424:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:ERROR:  /dashboard;jsessionid=26uqw2kydt3v4ehzfgj2wgo9
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No service handler registered with id org.eclipse.rwt.internal.uicallback.UICallBackServiceHandler
    at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.service.ServiceManager.getCustomHandlerChecked(ServiceManager.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.service.ServiceManager.getHandler(ServiceManager.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.engine.RWTServlet.handleValidRequest(RWTServlet.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.engine.RWTServlet.doPost(RWTServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.osgi.internal.CutOffContextPathWrapper.service(CutOffContextPathWrapper.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager$InternalHttpServiceServlet.service(HttpServerManager.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1065)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:900)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:954)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:538)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm using the com.eclipsesource.tabris.feature.feature.group 0.7.0.v20120828-1253

I have also tested the Train Dashboard Demo from http://developer.eclipsesource.com/tabris/demos/ it accurs the same Problem but in the screencast it looks like it worked in the past...

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

An update of the iOS client was released via Testflight for fix the problem (It was introduced by a change in RAP).
The Train Dashboard Demo was also updated for Tabris 0.7.0